# Open a controller in a new window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way to open a part of the application in a new Window. Specifically, I want a certain controller which I want to open in a new window. I don't want to use a modal, because I want the user to have the capability to use the main app and the functionality provided by this controller independently.

I'm using

```
var location = this.$state.href('moveout', { param: 'param_value' });
this.$window.open(location, 'popup', 'toolbar=no');
```

to open a new window. But when the new window opens, I see a copy of the entire application running on the other window instead of just the controller I want running. Is there any way to do this?

This is my state

```
.state('moveout', {
  url: '/moveout/:itemId',
  controller: 'MoveOutController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'app/moveout.html',
  params: {
    itemId: null
  }
})
```

Comment: Each window requires it's own instance of the app. You could create a state that only uses that controller and associated view for it

Comment: Can you share a link on how to do that? I have not used ui-router in the past.

Comment: Read router docs

Comment: It worked. Thanks!